# Comparing my statistic with site statistics in data explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer, statistics

Sometimes I feel that I'm just not getting (m)any answers on my questions... But is it so? I decided to first try the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) to find out if I have any reason to pity myself. Because I'm no MySQL master [I just started guessing the syntax](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/255838#graph):

```
SELECT sum(AnswerCount)/count(*) FROM Posts WHERE OwnerUserId=##UserId## GROUP BY AnswerCount

SELECT sum(AnswerCount)/count(*) FROM Posts WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY AnswerCount
```

From the queries I expect two numbers - one that applies to me one that applies to selected site. The idea is to divide sum of answers total by sum of questions asked. This, of course, gives you just two average amounts of answers per question

What I would prefer is % of questions without answer in the query.

Then it would be nice to see some graph like this:

[image: percentage of unanswered questions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried doing this all in SEDE but I'll leave that for someone else that knows more.

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) there is **951,056** questions with 0 answers on Stack Overflow.
According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) there is **8,556,980** questions in total.

Which gives us **11.1%** of questions with 0 answers.

You have [249](https://stackoverflow.com/users/607407/tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-zato?tab=questions) questions on Stack Overflow.
You have [49](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/259764/test) questions that have 0 answers.

Which means **19.7%** of your questions have 0 answers.

So in this particular case, you are having more unanswered questions than the site average.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/259772/query-for-tomas-zato?UserId=607407

There are only two data points, though, so I see no real reason to make it into a graph. (And plus, the SEDE graph tab only generates line graphs, not bar graphs.)

Note that the criterion used here ("having zero answers") is not the criterion used for the "unanswered" tab - that shows questions that have zero upvoted-or-accepted answers.